# prevent ogr2ogr from generating new fid attribute field

Tags: postgis, gdal, export, ogr2ogr, gml

I am exporting data from PostGIS to gml using python script with ogr2ogr. But the output generates unwanted new field  "fid" that contains the following string: "sql_statement.0" , "sql_statement.1", ... and so on. Is there a way to prevent this? I already have a field with unique feature identifiers. 
[image]

```
cmd = ogr2ogr + " -f  \"GML\" " + filename + " PG:" + db_connect + " -sql " + query
```

Comment: alias your PK column `AS fid`: *ogr2ogr* wants that identifier for GML, and it seems the driver will add that field in any case.

Comment: Thanks, that did exactly what I needed. :)

Comment: Could you write that as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

From @ThingumaBob comment:

alias your PK column AS fid: ogr2ogr wants that identifier for GML, and it seems the driver will add that field in any case.

Aliasing the collumn I wanted as fid worked and no new attribute field was created when exporting to gml.